# Does British English have a word for dry, starchy savoury snacks that are not fried slices of potato?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, hypernyms

Everyone, the world over, enjoys savoury snacks, particularly dry, starchy ones. Far and away the most popular kind in the Anglosphere are the ones made from deep-fried (sometimes baked) thinly-sliced potato (sometimes other root vegetables), almost always salted, and very often flavoured in some way. In Britain, we call these *crisps*, whilst in America, they call them *chips*.

However, there are dry, starchy, savoury snacks that are not these. There are (taking UK examples) Twiglets, Mini Cheddars, Quavers, Skips, Cheesy Wotsits, tortilla chips, Hula Hoops, Scampi Fries, small rice cakes, pretzels, various Phileas Fogg thingies, etc. They are made of potato, maize, wheat, or frankly who knows what (wood pulp?), with plenty of salt and vegetable oil thrown in to ensure deliciousness. I wouldn't call these crisps.

So what can I call them? There is *snack*, but that is a much more general term, that just means a small amount of food eaten between meals. Do we have a word for these things or not?

A New Zealander friend calls all these things "*chips*, bro", but that doesn't seem at all right to me. However, it did set me to wondering if we had an equivalent term.

Comment: It's just savoury snacks isn't it?  I can't think of anything that I'd call a savoury snack that isn't one of those items.  You could make home-cooked snacks of course but that's unusual imo.

Comment: I know this is not a question about AmE. "Savoury snacks" or even "savory snacks" is not a phrase we use in the US. I was about to ask what they are, but I guess that's the gist of the question, isn't it?

Comment: A friend reports that her French grandmother called such things *magnie-magnia* (pronounced something like *manee-manya*), but that this was probably a nonsense term she'd made up.

Comment: @Kit: It's not a term we use in the UK either. The problem is that i don't have a term to use! I think the classic US example is the Cheeto (basically the same thing as a Cheesy Wotsit, i think), which is clearly like a potato chip, but equally clearly is not a potato chip, being neither made of potato, nor chipped off anything, nor making any attempt to pretende that they are.

Comment: That's funny, I was sure the question didn't originally include the exact words "savoury snacks" but the revision history seems to say it was always there \-:

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Nibbles" is what they would collectively called if at a party.  I think that's the closest you'll get.

Comment: Nibbles is pretty good. I tend to think that these things only become nibbles when poured into a bowl at a party, but that term does cover exactly this range of foods - or would you call olives nibbles?

Comment: I like *nibbles*. It sounds very pleasant.  This is probably what we would use in the US, or maybe "nibblers".

Comment: This is my favourite so far but it technically goes beyond the scope of the question since it also includes things such as nuts.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: *Nibbles* certainly includes olives so far as I'm concerned. But crisps are nibbles too, so I'm a bit flummoxed by OP's question title. It apparently seeks a word that means exactly and only *Nibbles*, **excluding** *crisps*. A bit like asking for a word that means *All pizza toppings* **except** *pepperoni*. Then someone else will ask for another word meaning the same, but not including anchovies. Where will it all end?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It will end in a nirvana of terminological precision! I would be more than happy with a term that included crisps. Including olives seems a step too far, though.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: We can be masters of our own linguistic and alimentary destiny! I don't much like Twiglets, so I'll start by sharing with you **mmmpph**. Which you can take to mean "Assorted nibbles, all types *except* Twiglets and olives".

Answer (score 16):

As a Brit I would still refer to Wotsits and Quavers as crisps. Anything that comes in a crisps-bag is crisps to me.

All the other things you mentioned I would call nibbles.

Comment: Quavers, Hula-Hoops, and Skips are certainly very crisp-like. I bridle at calling them crisps, though. Crisps are crisps! And Wotsits are even more different. As for bags, isn't a Mini Cheddars bag substantially the same as a Hula Hoops bag? Can it even be legitimate to classify the contents by the nature of the bag?

Comment: @Tom - mini cheddars are an edge case, but Quavers, Hula-Hoops and Skips are called crisps by most people in the UK whether you like it or not!

Comment: They may very well be. Once again, my countrymen sorely disappoint me.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: I'm with you. Crisps and Hula-Hoops may meet up at various social gatherings. Sit on the same side-table, even. But they're not married, and never shall be, so they can't share a name.

Comment: Maybe we have identified one of the elusive differences between the two terms *crisps* and *chips*! I'm pretty sure I've seen British and Irish call our extruded snacks *crisps* here in Australia but us locals would never call them *chips*.

Comment: *Crisps* is fine. They may not be *potato* crisps, but starchy crispy things like Quavers, Hula-Hoops and Quavers all make that crispy crunch sound when bitten.

Comment: Quavers and Hula Hoops are both made of potato - just not slices of potato.

Answer (score 11):

In Dutch, we call this subset of snacks 'zoutjes' ('zout' salt + 'je' diminutive +'s' plural). So salties perhaps? :-)

Comment: Not a word that yet exists in English, afaik, but a good one; perhaps we should borrow it!

Comment: That's a good word. Does zoutjes exclude or include crisps?

Comment: I want to +1 this because I like it but since it's not an English word it should've been a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Tom: according to the dictionary definition, zoutjes include any kind of cold, fat, savoury snack that you can eat in front of the TV or at birthday parties. So yes, crisps, other starchy things, but also peanuts, pretzels, prawn crackers & stuff like that.

Comment: @hippietrail, Nelleke is recommending *salties*, which is an attempt to coin an English word. Nelleke, you might want to bold the word

Answer (score 9):

In Australia where we moved from *crisps* to *chips* several decades ago there is no special set term for crunchy snacks generally but there is the fairly common phrase "*savoury snack*". (You may also choose to omit the "u" if you prefer).

**UPDATE**

While Googling further on this answer I came across what I take to be an unappetizing industry term, "*extruded snack*", which covers many of these kinds of snacks **except** chips. For instance in Australia this would cover the popular *Twisties*™, *Cheezels*™, and *Burger Rings*™.

Comment: *Extruded snack* doesn’t cover quite all the snacks in question, if I understand it correctly: it wouldn’t for instance include pretzels, rice cakes, or Twiglets™.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't even cover chips/crisps but I thought the OP or some casual browsers might find it interesting or helpful nonetheless. But now I have to find out what a Twiglet is (-:

Comment: Extruded snack is a good term - precise, already in use, and mildly repellent, which is an ideal fit for this kind of industrial foodstuff.

Comment: +1 for *extruded snack* and *Burger Rings*, which actually caused me to throw up a little in my mouth.  Seriously, what is a *Burger Ring*? That sounds disgusting, like pork rinds.

Comment: My New Zealander friend reports that Burger Rings are one of the best kinds of chips. Also, "disgusting, like pork rinds" is a confusing construction, since pork scratchings (which i think is what we call pork rinds) are delicious (but, for clarity, are *not* extruded snacks).

Comment: @PLL: Some of the Google image search results did in fact include pretzels and rice cakes but that could just be coincidence. And if I found the right Twiglets I'm pretty sure they are extruded.

Comment: @hippietrail: Hmm.  In terms of manufacture, I’d have thought that Twiglets were much closer to pretzels than to hula hoops, cheezels, etc; and I would be surprised if this counts as extruded.  But we’re on the internet, so I’ve [asked some people who might know better](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/are-twiglets-an-extruded-snack)!  (Though I fear they may close it as off-topic.)

Comment: @PLL: When I first looked for photos of your Twiglets I thought they looked like our Twisties... but now I'm not so sure at all. Searches for Twiglet machines or factories turn up nothing.

Comment: @TomAnderson - hear hear. Pork rinds (also Pork Scratchings in the UK) *are* delicious.

Answer (score 3):

This one may not be particularly common. But it really grinds my gears when I do hear it, so I probably overestimate the actual frequency of occurrence...

**snacky-poos**

Aaarrrgggghhhh!

EDIT: I see someone's seen fit to downvote this one. It doesn't make sense to suppose that's because they don't *like* the term (after all, I don't either, but I still posted it). So I'll assume at least someone doesn't believe it's used at all. It's a spoken rather than written form, obviously, but [here's a published instance](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WociAQAAMAAJ&q=%22snacky%20poos%22&dq=%22snacky%20poos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yMVUT_64M8ag0QXTqNn0Cw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA) from the weekly American marketing trade journal [Brandweek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandweek) (now *Adweek*), and [here are 1500 instances](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22snacky+poos%22&pbx=1&oq=%22snacky+poos%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=12&gs_upl=0l0l1l560348l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&gs_l=hp.12...0l0l1l560348l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3b6b42e17dd83c7b&biw=1264&bih=902) from Google on the Internet at large.

Comment: Agreed, it is foul.

I'm now going to have to search english.stackexchange for the execrable 'amazeballs'.

Phew.  https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CrqlFojWgAAtmbp.jpg

Comment: @5arx: I guess the crappy SO site search facilities don't index comments. A Google site-specific search finds it [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216516/synonym-for-wow#comment672972_216516) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105628/how-should-one-use-awesome-today#comment215234_105628).

Comment: Then humanity (and Stack Exchange) could well be doomed.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't catchy and doesn't apply globally (e.g. Pringles are a bit of an edge case here being potato based but not 'chipped off' a potato.), but `corn[-based] snack` seems to be the description favoured by manufacturers and food labellers. C.f. Monster Munch, Wotsits, Onion rings/Ringos, Frazzles, Space Raiders etc. which are popular non-potato-based snacks in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most accurate description would be "salty" or "crispy" snacks. I think most listeners would understand what you meant by that.