# Is there an English word meaning "snacks eaten as an accompaniment while drinking alcohol"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, food

I'm currently travelling in Korea and Japan and learned that both languages have words specifically for snacks that accompany alcoholic drinks, or at least go with beer and spirits such as sake or soju. It can include but is not limited to chips and nuts, sometimes salty or spicy. But it occurred to me that English doesn't have an equivalent word. The best I can think of are "snack", "munchies", "nibbles", and "finger food".

For those wondering, the Japanese word is "おつまみ" (otsumami) and the Korean word is "안주" (anju).

What's the best English word for a drinking snack?

Comment: Related: [Does British English have a word for dry, starchy savoury snacks that are not fried slices of potato?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26374/3320)

Comment: I didn't really want to request a "single word"! A short phrase would suit me just as well.

Comment: In some communities the word for food served with alcohol would be "*food*". ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the Spanish word **tapa** is often used in English, which means precisely that. From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> 1953 C. *Salter Introducing Spain* iv.
>   36, I should like to draw attention
>   to...the admirable habit of the ‘**tapa**’.
>   In Spain, when you order a drink in a
>   bar..., you will always be
>   given...something to eat.
>
> 1959 W. *James Word-bk. Wine* 186
>   **Tapas**, small dishes served gratis in
>   boat-shaped saucers with every glass
>   of wine ordered...in a Spanish bodega or
>   café.
>
> 1964 C. *Rougvie Medal from Pamplona*
>   vi. 79 Must be a pub there with
>   **tapas**...these bits of food they give you
>   free with the booze.
>
> 1978 J. *Hyams Pool vi.* 74 She had
>   **tapas** and white wine at Café Monaco
>   with a friend.
>
> 1982 D. *Serafín Madrid Underground*
>   63 It was the hour to take **tapas** or
>   pre-dinner snacks.

Comment: I think this is the closest to a "general bar nibbles" word that English has!

Comment: In Australia I've only heard *tapas* used in *tapas bars*, which specifically try to mimic the kind of places found in Spain, so I would say there is a strong association which keeps it from being used for bar nibbles generally. Despite this it does seem to be the closest answer to my question and when I asked my Japanese friend for an English translation of "otsumami" she immediately answered "tapas".

Comment: I think "often" is pushing it...

Comment: @T.E.D.: Perhaps so. It also depends on where one usually eats. I don't think English has a real word for it.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to vote for "drinking/beer/bar snack" based on transitive translation from Japanese to Russian to English:

- In Russian, food given with alcohol (otsumami) is called "закуска" (zakuska). Among sources for translation: http://biablasta.ru/raznovidnosti-edy/cukemono-2.html
- Despite a very strong connotation of being alcohol companion, it is officially translated into English as "snack" (based on several russian-english dictionaries I checked).

Therefore, a good translation would merely add the alcohol connotation, e.g. "beer snack" or "alcohol snack" or especially **"bar snack".**

Comment: "Bar snack" is an accepted term in Australia, and is a good answer. +1.

Comment: +1 for "bar snack" which is very good but makes it sound like something you wouldn't eat with drinks at home, but -1 for using "officially translated" which is totally misleading about the nature of translation.

Comment: @hippietrail - please clarify what you mean re: "misleading about the nature of translation"?

Comment: @DVK: Who approves an official translation?

Comment: @hippietrail - whoever is the editor of a well-accepted widely used dictionary. In case of russian-englisg, there are several (including online) and they all agreee.

Comment: @DVK: In the languages I know, "snack" can only be translated in context because it could be one of various words with overlapping semantics. I would regard this as "glossing" and hence much less than an "official translation", though still very useful. Of course Russian is not a language I know.

Comment: A "bar snack" in the UK is a small meal (starter-sized) that can be bought in a pub.

Comment: I’m not sure whether bar snacks are those little bowls of crunchy-munchies, or whether they’re actual menu items one orders. Sometimes a bar will have a little menu that says snacks, but it’s just typical pub-fare not real meals.

Answer (score 5):

A French word for food that is often associated with drinks is *[hors d'oeuvre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hors_d%27%C5%93uvre)*; it is widely used in English.

Comment: I have actually seen "hors d'oeuvre" written in katakana on packs of otsumami in Japan so a definite +1.

Answer (score 4):

I believe ***Munchies*** is the right word. The other words you suggested would mean other types of food as well. But munchies is almost synonymous with beer snacks.

Another specific word used in the same context is ***canapé***.

**EDIT**

One source describing the usage of canape as a drink snack is Wikipedia. This is the link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canap%C3%A9#Details

Similarly, Encarta World English Dictionary mentions the association of Munchies and Canape with drinks

http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?lextype=3&search=canape

http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?lextype=3&search=munchies

Comment: Is there some documentation that shows association of munchies with alcohol? Merriam-Websters didn't mention that (I'm ESL, and from my limited cultural knowledge of the topic munchies is associated more with Marijuana). Same question for canapé's context. Thanks!

Comment: The definition for canape can be found here - http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?lextype=3&search=canape

Comment: Similarly, the definition for munchies can be found here - http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?lextype=3&search=munchies

Comment: Alternatively you may just bing the definition using "define:" in the search bar.

Comment: You might also want to check the usage contexts for canape at the wikipedia link here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canap%C3%A9#Details

Comment: @Sri - I googled using "define:" and didn't come up with anything by 420 (MJ) stuff :)

Comment: @DVK. I know. Google sucks. Move over to Bing. ;)

Comment: +1 for bringing "canapé" to my attention, which I was only familiar with in a broader sense, but -1 for spamvertising Bing.

Comment: I use *munchies* all the time with absolutely no association with alcohol.

Comment: __Canapes__ are finger food served at high class parties, often by waiters in tuxes, and so have low association with beer or a bar drinks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canap%C3%A9#Details mentions that the canapes are often used to encourage people to drink more. However, it is understandable that 'outside of this often' group, there might be occasions where it serves as a high class party food.

Comment: @Sri: @Mitch is right, canapes go with cocktails (or wine), not beer.  The link you give is quite explicit about this.

Comment: @hippietrail: Hey Bing isn't that bad these days.

Comment: @Rhodri: Well. One. The question was for a drinking snack. It did not exclude cocktails and wine. And, I believe they are alcoholic drinks as well. Two. The questions asked for the best single word which is specific to a drinking snack.And munchies and canape were the closest I could remember.

Comment: @Sri: don't get me wrong, they aren't bad answers.  They are not both generic and drinking-related, though (in other words, I don't think this question has a single right answer).

Comment: "munchies" was my favourite answer until "tapas" showed up. Munchies had at least an element of craving and the distant association through one of its other senses to accompaniment with consuming regulated substances helped a tiny bit against the other broad terms. But in the end the range of foods that can be in tapas match the range of otsumami and anju much better despite its ethnic feel.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a non-native speaker use "munchies". In some contexts this word implies Marijuana usage.

Answer (score 3):

A British term that's caught on in the US: **[pub grub](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pub+grub)**.

Comment: Pub grub is generally any food that can be *bought* at a pub (in the UK at least), and as such couldn't be defined as a snack. Burgers, steak and ale pie, bangers and mash and ploughman's are all examples of "pub grub" that are in themselves a hearty meal - certainly not snacks.

Comment: @jozzas: Never underestimate that which an American would consider a "snack" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It seems [Beer Nuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_Nuts) should be mentioned here:

> Beer Nuts is a brand of snack food building on the original product, peanuts with a "unique" sweet-and-salty glazing made to a "secret recipe" [...] the name is intended to suggest to customers that they go well with beer. Many believe that Beer Nuts, with their high salt content, encourage people to order more beer in bars.

The phrase has come to mean any nuts served at a bar:

> It's the name that grabs people's attention and sticks in their memories: [Beer Nuts](http://www.beertravelers.com/lists/beernuts.html). Two words that say it all. In fact, the name is almost too perfect. Like Band-Aids and Kleenex, the name Beer Nuts has taken on the taint of the generic, which is why the company branded the name a few years ago. "Some people thought it was any nut you ate with beer," said Jim Tipton, manager of marketing communications.

Comment: Q: What's the difference between Beer Nuts and deer nuts?  A:  Beer Nuts are 99 cents a bag; deer nuts are just under a buck.

Answer (score 3):

Which word I'd use depends on the setting:

A formal setting with drinks, I'd say hors d'oeuvres.

If it's at home with family and friends, tapas.

If I'm at a bar, or in the process of a barcrawl - bar food, beer nuts, munchies, snacks or grub.

Answer (score 2):

Direct from the OED (and straight from French):

> **amuse-gueule**, n.
>
> Brit. /əˈm(j)uːzˌgəːl/, U.S.
>   /əˈm(j)uzˈgəl/
>
> Plural unchanged, -s
>
> [‹ French amuse-gueule (1946), lit.
>   ‘(that which) amuses the mouth’ ‹
>   amuser amuse v. + gueule (see gullet
>   n.).]
>
> Esp. in French cookery: a small
>   savoury item of food served as an
>   appetizer. Also fig.
>
> - **1963 News Herald** (West Lake County,
>     Ohio) 7 May 6/1 
>   *There were seven
>     courses, seven wines and liquors. At
>     the reception‥various appetizers
>     listed as **Amuse Gueule** (amuse the
>     gullet).*
> - **1977 Time** 28 Nov. 31/2
>     
>   *From the **amuse-gueules** to the
>     mignardises, everything is exquisite,
>     and so is the bill: $100 to $150 for
>     two.*
> - **1993 Times** 15 Feb. 29/1, *I am
>     not alone in lamenting the decline of
>     those short film that used to precede
>     the main feature in cinema programmes,
>     performing the dual role of
>     unpredictable **amuse-gueule** and subtle
>     incitement to purchase unwanted orange
>     squash.*
> - **2002 Wall St. Jrnl.** 29 Mar.
>     w10/3 
>   *But there's much to admire,
>     starting with an **amuse gueule** of
>     kippers transformed into a delicate,
>     smoky pudding-like cream topped with a
>     parsley sorbet.*

Comment: In English, I'd say the more formal *"amuse-bouche"* [has become more popular](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=amuse+bouche%2Camuse+gueule&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of [late](http://www.google.com/trends?q=amuse-bouche%2Camuse-gueule), however, it is usually used to refer to a small bite at the start of a larger meal; it is rarely used to refer to a snack that is eaten throughout a drinking session.

Answer (score 2):

Bluntly, there isn't a generic word for alcohol-related snacks.  As others have suggested, *canapés* and *tapas* are particular types of snack foods associated with particular types of alcohol in particular contexts.  The general "snack" words — *munchies*, *nibbles* and so on — don't have a particular association with alcohol.  There may be some terms that work in some regions, like *bar snacks* (which unfortunately has a different specific meaning in the UK), but nothing universal.