# Synonym for wow

Tags: synonyms

**Wow**, the teams are getting better!

What alternatives are there to the word *wow*?

I have looked at thesaurus.com, synonym.com, thesaurus.yourdictionary.com, my own personal thesaurus

What is wrong is they all give me synonyms for 'to wow someone' I need synonyms for someone saying wow like they are in awe or just saying wow.

Comment: I'm doing commentating on a football game. I have wrote most of it out but I need to improve it by adding a synonym for wow since I use it too much. I have looked t other sites but they all use wow in a way which doesn't fit so that's why.

Comment: I think all the synonyms are listed here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:wow

Comment: “Ay caramba and jumping Jehoshaphat, the teams are getting better!”

Comment: OMG!  Shut the front door!  Egads!  Golly gee willikers!  Amazeballs!  STFU!  Well I'll be a blue nosed gopher!  Jiminy Christmas!  Shazam!  A failure to come up with synonyms for "wow" wows with a lack of imagination.

Answer (score 1):

"Wow" is a slang interjection; hence, all synonyms will be slang. A slang dictionary might help. But these terms change rapidly, they are fads. "Wow!" has survived longer than most, but is still not formal register.